# How can I create a file with `/` in its file name?

Tags: python

I'm writing a Crawler in Python and I'm trying to save the `html` of the crawled pages in a file with the name of the urls. However, the urls have slashes in it, which is probably the reason why my code below is not working.

```
path = "directory/subdirectory"
url = "http://stackoverflow.com/"
    file_path = path + "/" + url
      tmp = open(file_path, 'a')
      tmp.write(html)
      tmp.close()
```

How can I create a file with `/` in its name?

Please, consider that the `directory/subdirectory` already exists.

**Update:**

As our friend `@jorgeh` mentioned, we can convert the `/` to ASCII code. So, even though this question might be a duplicate, it has a different solution.

Comment: Ok, then a nice solution would be converting `/` to ascii code...

Comment: In your particular case, you could use `urllib` with the `safe` argument:
`print urllib.quote("string/with/slashes", '')`

Comment: @jorgeh: I voted to reopen this question, so you can post it as an answer, because your solution worked for me.

Comment: Any reason you don't want to replace slashed with underscores? Or do you want to retain the full path?

Comment: yep, I need the full path